# How to do a vlookup for multiple data separated by comma in google sheets Apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, vlookup

I have a google sheet to create a vlookup.

Sheet 1

|  | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Categories | Category ID |
| 2 | ab, ac, bd |  |
| 3 | ac |  |
| 4 | av, ab |  |

Sheet 2

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Category | Category slug | category Id |
| ab | /ab/ | 1 |
| ac | /ac | 2 |
| av | /av | 3 |

I want to do a vlookup as shown below.

|  | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Categories | Category ID |
| 2 | ab, ac, bd | 1,2,bd |
| 3 | ac | 2 |
| 4 | av, ab | 3,1 |

The requirements are:

1. Mapping / Create a vlookup for all data in a cell
2. Reversing the same data wherever vlookup data is not available

I tried to create a function in the script editor. But things didn't work out the way I expected.

```
function replace_category_with_id(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("T");
  var total = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,7,total,1);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var asheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("A");
  var atotal = asheet.getLastRow();
  var arange = asheet.getRange(2,1,atotal-1,3);
  var avalues = arange.getValues();
  
  //Create an array variable result
  var results =[{}];

  //Run a for loop for the values in the T Spreadsheet
  for(var i=0; i<values.length-1; i++)
  {
    //Split multiple data in a cell
    var splitdata = values[i].toString().split(",");
    
    //Search if the individual data in splitdata is available
    for(var count=0; count<(splitdata.length); count++)
    {
      //Create a flag to check if the search has found the data
      var flag = 0;
      for(var n=0; n<avalues.length-1;n++)
    {
      //Logger.log(avalues[n]);
      if(splitdata[count] == avalues[n][0])
      {
        Logger.log(i);
        Logger.log(count);
        Logger.log(n);
        //results[i][count] = avalues[n][2];
        flag = 1;
      }
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
      results[i][count] = splitdata[count];
    }

    }

    //Logger.log(values[i]);
     
  } 

  //Display Results array
  for(var i=0; i<=results.length; i++)
  {
    Logger.log(results[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Rubén I wasn't confident with the attempts that I have made. That's the reason I didn't the code earlier. I have included it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some modifications to your code and added comments to each process.

Try this:

```
function replace_category_with_id(){
  //Retrieve Sheet1 data
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var total = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet1.getRange(2,7,total-1,1);
  var sheet1_values = range.getValues();
  //Retrieve Sheet2 data
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var atotal = sheet2.getLastRow();
  var arange = sheet2.getRange(2,1,atotal-1,3);
  var sheet2_values = arange.getValues();
  
  //Sheet2: Create object as lookup 
  var lookup = {};
  sheet2_values.forEach(element => {
    //Push each element and use Category as key and Category ID as value
    lookup[element[0]] =  element[2]  
  })

  var result = [];
  sheet1_values.forEach(element => {
    //Sheet1: Split each categories in the first column.
    var val = element[0].toString().split(",");
    var val_str = [];
    val.forEach(element2 => {
      //Sheet1: Check if Category exists in lookup, if not use Category
      if(lookup.hasOwnProperty(element2)){
        val_str.push(lookup[element2])
      }else{
        val_str.push(element2);
      }
    })
    //Combine results in an Array
    result.push([val_str.join(",")])
  })

  //Set values to sheets using the combined results.
  sheet1.getRange(2,8,total-1,1).setValues(result);
  
}
```

Here is my sample data:
*(I added some test data to check if the logic is working)*
**Sheet1**

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]